WebGL.getUniformLocation Offset usage
I'm new to WebGL, i have the code below:
var n = WebGL.createProgram();
WebGL.useProgram(n);

WebGL.uniform1i(WebGL.getUniformLocation(n, "uO"), 2880);

What this command means, Offset textures "uO" by 2880 pixels or what ?
I think Offset works by 8x8 = 64 pixels ?

Without knowing the actual shader code this could mean anything.

read some tutorials?
